# PHP Session is null when accessed in a different script

Tags: php, session

I'm setting a session like so:

```
// ---- Start the session
session_start();
.
.
.
.

$tokenMap = $_SESSION["tokenMap"];
$date = new DateTime();
$created = $date->getTimestamp();
$accessToken = uniqid();
if (!isset($tokenMap))
  $tokenMap = array($accessToken=>array("username"=>$username, "created"=>$created));
else {
  // ---- Unset any values that already exist
  foreach($tokenMap as $t => $user) {
    if ($user["username"] === $username) {
      unset($tokenMap[$t]);
      break;
    }
  $tokenMap[$accessToken] = array("username"=>$username, "created"=>$created);
}
echo $_SESSION["tokenMap"]; // returns correct values
```

However, when I access it in a different script, `$_SESSION` is empty:

```
// ---- Start the session
session_start();

echo json_encode($_SESSION); // []
```

Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about PHP sessions?

Comment: You do not set any `$_SESSION` variable. `$tokenMap = $_SESSION["tokenMap"];` requests the variable from the session (you should test first if it exists!) but nowhere you set `$_SESSION['tokenMap'] = variable`

Comment: I do, check the first if statement.

Comment: My bad! I guess variables in PHP don't work the way I expect them to. I changed $tokenMap to $_SESSION["tokenMap"] and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Session variables are (after `session_start()`) as any other variable. You have to give them a value to access them.

Answer (score 0):

To make your session available you can create a table and save & update your session data when ever you need.